# How to increment md footnotes following a newly added footnote by 1?

Tags: markdown, footnotes

I have a long essay written in Md and published on my website. I have greatly enjoyed the format and was considering moving from using a rich text editor to just using markdown once I got **footnotes** up and running.

The syntax is as follows:

> “There is a mounting realization on the part of the world’s people that the decades ahead are set to bring with them challenges among the most daunting that the human family has ever had to face.”[^7]
>
> [^7]:[www.bahai.org/r/300076434](http://www.bahai.org/r/300076434)

However, I just hit a snag: I found a perfect quote to add midway through the text. Now I need to increment all the other 13 footnotes by one. Are there any established approaches to this issue? What is a sustainable way I can add new footnotes to the middle of a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the Markdown engine you're using. In [GitHub-Flavoured Markdown](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#footnotes), you can use any number or string for footnotes, and it will render as numbers in sequential order.

There don't seem to be many tools that directly update the markdown itself, but there are some that will [update an outputted HTML file](https://npm.io/package/@amanda-mitchell/remark-renumber-footnotes).

Comment: So, then it works to add a footnote in between with a unique string, just so long as it is distinct from the others, thanks this works great. Such as:

`[^6b]:`